# UITableView separator lines erratic in displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view of custom UITableViewCells that expand and contract (to display info) when they're touched. Unfortunately, depending on where the interaction is, some cell's separators (at the top/bottom of the cell's frame) disappear. It makes them appear as though two cells have joined into one.

Below is what I consider to be the relevant code (please let me know if less/more is needed):

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DynamicTableViewCell *selectedCell = (DynamicTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Trinomial *currentTri = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    switch (currentTri.cellDetailActive) {
    case YES:

        selectedCell.detailLabel.hidden = YES;
        [selectedCell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
        currentTri.cellDetailActive = NO;
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];

        break;
    case NO:

        selectedCell.detailLabel.hidden = NO;
        [selectedCell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
        currentTri.cellDetailActive = YES;
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];

        break;

    default:
        NSLog(@"Serious application error. BOOLEAN contains no value in -[tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]");
        break;
  }
}
```

And here is the method for setting the row heights:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Trinomial *tri = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (!tri.cellDetailActive)
    return 55;
else
    return 110;
}
```

Images of my issue are posted below. The process is that the cell holds a property that tells whether the detail info is displayed, and I make the cell height change (through `-[beginUpdates:]` and `-[endUpdates:]`), then hide or unhide some views, depending on the last display mode.

[image: Missing separator between collapsed cells]
[image: Missing separator between expanded cells]
[image: Separator present between collapsed cells]
[image: Separator present between expanded cells]

Please let me know if I need to clarify/elaborate on any information or provide any other materials. Thanks in advance for your help!!

**EDIT:**
Somehow, I had two versions of this method merged together, where there was incorrect code. How `-[tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]` should work is that there is an object from the Core Data fetched results controller received, containing a property called `cellDetailActive` that checks whether the cell is expanded or not. The cell doesn't have the cellDetailActive property, my apologies.

**EDIT #2:**
Okay, I filed a bug with Apple Bug Reporter (#17295019) titled "Table view cell separators disappear as cell height changes". Well, that title is a little misleading, because Apple's devs got back to me and said that because `-[setSelected:animated]` was being called on a table view cell directly, I was having separator issues. Instead, it was recommended that `[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition]` be used, along with `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated]` in my switch statement.

Comment: how are you getting "currentTri" in - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Sorry, there's `Trinomial *currentTri = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` tucked away in there that might've been missed in copying.

Comment: Off topic, but using switch with a `BOOL` can lead to unpredictable results due to inconsistent usage.  If you're trying to do trinary logic you should use an enum: `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, States) { Unknown, Off, On }`.  Otherwise, `if (currentTri.cellDetailActive) {} else {}` is safest.

Comment: @BrianNickel I got an out-of-the-blue warning today in Xcode with that same semantic issue. Did exactly what you did, works fine now. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a bug. The way I get around it is to set the separators to None and draw my own cell background which includes a line that functions as the separator.

Comment: Is it a bug with the table view, like I could report it to Apple? Or is it a bug in my code that I couldn't work around? Okay, I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: If you can reproduce it consistently in a simple version of your code, certainly, report it to Apple. I had this reported as bug #15005911, "Reloading a selected UITableViewCell erases its separator". It appeared to be fixed in iOS 7.0.3 but perhaps not.

Comment: Yes, I'll see what I can do. I'm running the iOS 7.1 SDK (and a 7.1 dev device), so it wasn't fixed for me, at least. Thanks for the suggestion and feedback!